# PLS-00103 on package body

Tags: plsql

I've created a Package spec and body and when I execute the script I get no errors. However my package body stays in invalid state. I can't understand why, can you please help?

Here's my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY CONFIG_MODULE_API AS
  FUNCTION APPLY_RULES(I_EVENT_ROWID      IN VARCHAR2,
                       I_EVENT_TABLE_NAME IN VARCHAR2,
                       I_EVENT_OPERATION  IN VARCHAR2,
                       O_EVENT_STAGE      OUT CFG_EVENT_STAGE,
                       O_STATUS_CODE      OUT VARCHAR,
                       O_ERROR_MSG        OUT VARCHAR) RETURN BOOLEAN IS
  BEGIN
    --no code yet
    RETURN NULL;
  END APPLY_RULES;

  PROCEDURE TEST_RULES(I_FILTER_ID        NUMBER,
                       I_EVENT_TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2,
                       O_SQL_STMT         OUT VARCHAR,
                       O_STATUS_CODE      OUT VARCHAR,
                       O_ERROR_MSG        OUT VARCHAR) IS
  BEGIN
   --no code yet
  END TEST_RULES;

END CONFIG_MODULE_API;
```

And here's the exception I get whenever I check the stack trace:

```
Compilation errors for PACKAGE BODY MYSHCEMA.CONFIG_MODULE_API

Error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:

          ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
          raise return select update while with <an identifier>
          <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
          continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
          savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
Line: 20
Text: END TEST_RULES;
```

What am I missing?
(My package spec, works fine.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a null statement after the BEGIN and before the END TEST_RULES (where it says no code yet.

```
BEGIN
  NULL;
END TEST_RULES;
```